# Within Jira, how to identify current team allocations?

Tags: jira

The objective is to pre-seed the user-project allocation matrix in HR system using the data pulled from Jira.  This allocation does not need to be 100% precise as it will then get reviewed, and subsequently managed inside the workforce planner part of HRM.

The challenge is, how to identify from the data in Jira, which people are working on which projects?

What we have tried so far: Simply see which issues in that project have been worked by which people within the last x days (such as 30 days).

This seems to give an ok working snapshot of user-project allocation.

Is there a better heuristic to consider?

Comment: You may want to consider removing your approach from your Question and including it as an Answer instead. As it stands, my own Answer to your Question would simply consist of "In my opinion, no." Instead of asking 'are there better ways than X to do Y?", consider just "How should I do Y?".

Comment: Have you looked at JIRA Portfolio's capacity plan report?  Here is an article that describes the basic concepts but I think it is exactly what you are looking for.  Portfolio even allows you to describe 'virtual' team members, for example, if you are doing workforce planning for a contract that hasn't been awarded yet, you can actually model that out in portfolio.  https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/agile-capacity-planning

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to create a JIRA filter based on your project(s). Once you have created the filter, you can create a JIRA dashboard and add a piechart gadget incorporating the filter.

JIRA filters  are easily exported in excel format, providing the snapshot you need.